# subprocess.call says there's no such file or directory, but os.path.isfile says there is

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an executable file that I'd like to run from Python. I define a path variable pointing at it:

```
>>> path = '/root/Cognos/Cognos/linuxi38664h/issetupnx'
```

I verify that I am in fact pointing at a file and not a directory:

```
>>> from os.path import isdir, isfile
>>> isdir(path)
False
>>> isfile(path)
True
```

But as soon as I try to run the executable file via `subprocess.call`...

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call([path])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It tells me the file doesn't exist now.

The only possibility I can think of is that maybe the executable itself is being found and run fine, but the executable is failing saying that something it needs (what?) isn't found. I'm not sure how I would test this theory, though... or even if it's possible.

Another possibility might be some kind of permissions issue? Although I can't think of why I would have proper permissions to see the file but then I suddenly wouldn't be able to see it the moment I try running it.

Comment: are you on Unix-ish or Windows?

Comment: CentOS. Python is version 2.7.5, if that's important.

Comment: is the executable bit set? `ls -l /root/Cognos/Cognos/linuxi38664h/issetupnx`

Comment: never mind - on python 2.7.3, at least, attempting to execute a file without the `x` bit responds with `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`, a different error

Comment: do you observe a difference between using `call(path)` and using `call([path])`?

Comment: Can you try to run `call([path], shell=True)`?

Comment: @JacobKrall - Running `ls -l` shows that the flags are `-rwxrwxr-x`

Comment: Have a look at this:  http://portal2portal.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/ibm-business-monitor-856-cognos-and.html   You might be missing shared libraries.

Comment: Great catch, @JoeYoung. @ArtOfWarfare can you run `ld /root/Cognos/Cognos/linuxi38664h/issetupnx` from your shell?

Comment: @RetoAebersold - That prints out this: `-s: /root/Cognos/Cognos/linuxi38664h/issetupnx: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory 
126`

Comment: Try jumping to the bottom of that blog and installing the 3 libs the author lays out

Comment: @JoeYoung - Thanks! That appears to have worked perfectly. Too bad Python wasn't able to spit out a more useful error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `call`, I should have used `check_output`. Then the error would have included all of the messages printed to `stdout` and `stderr`.

```
path = '/root/Cognos/Cognos/linuxi38664h/issetupnx'

from subprocess import check_output
check_output([path])
```

Then I would have gotten a more detailed message about how it failed to load shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

execute this code as root:

```
import subprocess as sp

path = '/root/Cognos/Cognos/linuxi38664h/issetupnx'

proc = sp.Popen([path],stdin=sp.PIPE)

proc.communicate()
```

Comment: [@Joe Young's comment suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660438/subprocess-call-says-theres-no-such-file-or-directory-but-os-path-isfile-says#comment53167843_32660438) that the issue is unrelated to redirecting stdin in any way. I don't understand why the answer is upvoted. It doesn't help with the issue at all.